# I shared my bank account number and my name, can they drain my account?

Tags: bank-account, fraud, uae

I shared my bank account number and my name with my gmail info with an online trading company. Do I need to worry? Can they drain my bank account?

Comment: By gmail info, do you mean only your e-mail address, or also your password?

Answer (score 3):

They can not drain your bank account unless they have your online banking credentials. Businesses do send their name and account number on letterheads, you know, so people can pay their invoices.

Comment: Please check JB Couinard's comment on the question: if you gave the your e-mail password, they may be able to get or reset your online banking credentials.

Answer (score 1):

This is a completely routine thing, that information is required for any electronic transfers to take place.

In theory they can use it to drain your money by initiating a transfer the same as if you were transferring money, but if an improper transfer were done your bank would reverse it if you tell them soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

Every bank account I have requires two factor authentication to set up a new destination for your money, so if you have fingerprint authentication on your phone don't let them steal your phone and your finger